# UiPopOver in Iphone

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uipopovercontroller, popover

I have an image of the UiPopOver
[image]

I want to make it bigger or smaller based on the text that i want to display in this. My plan is that i will adda text view inside the image view and scale it accordingly. I am facing difficulty in scaling the image to bigger or smaller.

For example if i know that the text that will fit in it have size of CGSize(80, 100), the how i can scale this image view to a specified size without pixelation.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can make the *resizable image* with the following insets (their positions marked by the colourful lines below), that will do the job for you:

[image]

you can find more information about how you can me a resizable image in the `UIImage` *[Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimage_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets:)*, the related method's name is `–resizableImageWithCapInsets:`.